# Heroku Git Push Master Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, heroku, cloud9

I have an app deployed on Heroku. I simple cloned the app onto cloud9 IDE to make some changes like so:

```
heroku git:clone -a myApp
```

After that I tried to push the changes following this:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

Its giving me the following error:

```
To https://git.heroku.com/myApp
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myApp'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: `git pull heroku master` and then push it. Or use force option `git push heroku master -f`.

Comment: @Tushar Thanks the force option solved the issue if post that as an answer I can accept it and close the question.

Comment: `git push heroku <your_current_branch>:main` solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

At first pull the master code & then push to heroku.

Pull from master :

```
git pull heroku master
```

Then Push to heroku :

```
git push heroku master
```

If you want to push your code forcefully :

```
git push heroku master -f
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git pull heroku master   
git push heroku master
```

other wise you can fetch merge and push.